# What does Limit at Min to Max values in datasheet means?

Tags: spi, clock, datasheet, pll

I have doubt while implementing I/O SPI interface for the ADF4158 PLL Synthesizer. I planned to use a simple I/O model to send bytes (using only 3 bits for 3 lines) using RS232 at 115200 BPS. I didn't implemented a proper SPI as I thought reading the datasheet, the device is not so time critical. But I have a doubt, what does the text in datasheet "Limit at TMIN to TMAX (C Version)" means? How can I find the max and min time periods, so that I'm sure the I/O based RS232 SPI lines works.

I am sending bytes to output pins like as below, to makeit behave like a SPI:
port.Write(new byte[] { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x01, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08 }, 0, 16);
//There are maximum 4 bits that goes HIGH, 3 for SPI (SCLK,CS',MOSI) and a trigger bit for reading function.

Below is the datasheet snap for timing:

[image]

Link to datasheet: http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADF4158.pdf (Page 5, I need only writing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a favorite phrase for authors of Analog Devices datasheets.

The T\$_{MIN}\$ and T\$_{MAX}\$ refer to the minimum and maximum operating temperature of the chip (−40°C to +125°C for Rev. C, as indicated on the Revision History on page 3, the latest version is actually Rev G).

Limit refers to the minimum value.  Why?  Because under the column labeled Unit it says "ns min".

As used this way, the limit doesn't always refer to just one value; for example in [this datasheet](http://www.roboard.com/Files/G211/AD7997_7998.pdf), the Limit At has columns for Min and Max in Table 3 on Page 7 (partially shown here):

[image]

So in your case, the phrase, "Limit At T\$_{MIN}\$ to T\$_{MIN}\$ (C Version)" means the minimum value of the relevant timing parameter (show on the left as t\$_{1}\$, t\$_{2}\$, etc.) over the temperature range of Rev. C of the chip.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. So I know the min timming period so that the SPI works, but does this statement says anything abaout the max timimng duration. Icaculated from my symbol rate and the high and low time are too high in micro second range.

Comment: @dDebug  Usually for something like SPI, there is no set maximum timing, you can run the bus 1000 times slower than the fastest possible value and it will still work.  (For example, I have worked with chips that are rated for 40 MHz, but I'm sure they would work at 40 kHz as well.)  But note in the table I am have added to my answer, which is for I2C, there are some maximum values since it is more structured.